# Добавление custom view + json

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-view

*Доброго времени суток. Я взаимодействую с вк и получаю json строку в которой сказано что у меня есть первый пост и в нем находится картинка, текст и видео. После того как распарсил данные я хочу сделать добавление `CardView` в свою программу в котором будут эти данные. Мне посоветовали сделать custom view через xml файл, то есть накидать в xml все что может быть и после уже добавить этот компонент к себе в главное активити.* 
**Вопрос:** если в *custom view(xml)* файле у меня будет накидано `ImageView`&&`TextView`, а после парсировки строки-ответа мне нужно будет добавить только `CardView`(он же custom view он же xml файл) в котором будет только текст или только картинка как такого достичь? Может лучше уже программно создавать каждый компонент, если да так это будет куча условий? Как лучше сделать и желательно маленький примерчик. Спасибо.

Comment: это уже зависит как будет выглядеть разметка. В любом случаем в xml создайте макет, которым будете пользоваться, там вы можете точно отрегулировать расположение элементов и их зависимости, поставьте видимость gone, в случае получения данных меняйте видимость и показываете, если есть необходимость, если данных нет сделайте шаблон в TextView например "Пусто". Всё зависит от желаемого результат, а программно придется делать вы же данные получаете в процессе, здесь тоже вариантов уйма. В целом на вопрос нельзя ответить конкретно

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, и что мне потом ифами тупо проверять каждый элемент?